# repost: Setting up express.js Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im encountering this error on replit while setting up my express server, im still starting to learn express so i still dont know some of it means

> 

```
/home/runner/log-in-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:513
  this.stack.push(layer);
             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at Function.route (/home/runner/log-in-API/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:513:14)
    at file:///home/runner/log-in-API/api/reviews.route.js:4:8
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
```

here is my index.js

```
import app from "./server.js"
import mongodb from "mongodb"
/* import ReviewsDao from "./dao/reviewsDAO.js " */

const dbUser = process.env['MONGO_USERNAME']
const dbPword = process.env['MONGO_PASSWORD']

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
const uri = `SECRET`

const port = 8000

MongoClient.connect(uri, {
  maxPoolSize: 50,
  wtimeoutMS: 2500,
  useNewUrlParser: true
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error(err.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
.then(async client => {
  await ReviewsDAO.injectDB(client)
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening to ${port}`)
  })
})
```

here is my server.js

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import reviews from "./api/reviews.route.js"

const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.use("/api/v1/reviews", reviews)
app.use("*", (req, res) => res.status(404).json({error: "not found"}))

export default app
```

and here is my reviews.route.js that is located inside a folder named api

```
import express from 'express'
const router = express.Router

router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world')
})

export default router
```

Am i missing something im trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nu_pCVPKzTk) by free code camp and im  currently at 6:16:30 timestamp

i tried to fix everything even typos, and im still encountering this problem what could be the problem ?

Comment: You likely want to invoke `Router`: `const router = express.Router()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is created because the way you structure your router, try `router.get('/', (req, res) => {` instead of `router.route('/').get((req, res) => {`. Does this work? And to initialise your router try `const router = express.Router();` instead of `const router = express.Router` (so call the factory function)

Comment: I still get the error when I do *router.get('/', (req, res) => {* ,and i initialize my router like that cause I change how I import packages in the package.json file, like this {"type": "module"}

Comment: I don't think changing that matters, you `express.Router` is a function which returns a `Router` object. Currently how I read it `const router` is not a `Router` object, but rather a reference to the `function` that returns a `Router` object.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood what you said, but its working now thank you so much!!